# How do I convert a std::basic_string<char> to a Rust readable value while reverse engineering a C++ program?

Tags: c++, pointers, rust, interop, ffi

I am doing a CTF where I was able to reverse engineer parts of the software and now I would like to read a value. I am doing this in Rust.

In my hooked function, I have the `__thiscall this` pointer stored in `_edx` (using `fastcall` to conserve overwriting that register), so I have a pointer to the class instance object inself. Through reverse engineering, I found that in the class `ClassA` at offset `0x2c` there is a pointer to a `ClassB` instance being stored, and in that `ClassB` instance, at offset `0x78` there is a `std::basic_string<char>` being stored that I would like to read.

My current code looks like this. `_edx` is a `DWORD` so it is interpreted as `u32`:

```
let real_p_this = _edx;

let player_name_location = (*(real_p_this + GameDeclarations::ActivePlayerInClientWorld as u32)) + GameDeclarations::PlayerNameInActivePlayer as u32;

return CwTickFn.call(p_this, _edx, float32);
```

I get a compilation error saying that I cannot dereference type `u32` which makes sense. I suspect first I am supposed to add `offset1` to `ClassA`, then add `offset2` to the value being stored in `ClassA`'s `offset1`, and interpret the resulting address as `std::basic_string<char>`, and after that convert the C++ `std::basic_string<char>` to a Rust-readable collection.

How can I go about it in Rust?

Comment: This is probably not possible without knowing the specific details of the C++ runtime library used by the application. C++ strings can either store their memory on the heap and just hold a pointer to it, or they could _sometimes_ hold the string within the string object itself (so-called "short string optimization"). You need to know the layout of the string object in memory to accomplish reading from a string like this, especially considering that you don't immediately know where the actual data is stored.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked in memory the region where the string is saved, and have only seen the string itself encoded as a series of 2 byte values. I couldn't see anywhere the length of the string or other related info and it didn't seem null terminated either.

I used Rust's `CStr::from_ptr` to read out the string from the memory address and it worked...

```
let player_name_loc = p_this + GameDeclarations::PlayerNameInActivePlayer as u32;

let player_name_as_mut = std::mem::transmute_copy::<DWORD, *mut i8>(&player_name_loc);

let player_name = CStr::from_ptr(player_name_as_mut);

let cw_this_str = format!("value of p_this: {:X?}, player name is: {:?}", p_this, player_name);
```

This gave me the string with correct length. Maybe it's a null terminated string? I don't know how it figured out its length.